# Calling a PHP page with GET variables from the Linux command line

Tags: php, linux, wkhtmltopdf, suse

I want to use `wkhtmltopdf` to convert a web page to a PDF file. I have a test with a static template and this syntax works perfectly:

```
wkhtmltopdf my.html my.pdf
```

The problem is the actual page is a dynamic PHP page with tables that rely on three HTML [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) variables.

An example would be:

```
http://mypage.php?clientid=SJC&datestart=201201&dateend=201202
```

I can't do this directly like so:

```
wkhtmltopdf mypage.php?clientid=SJC&datestart=201201&dateend=201202 my.pdf
```

Someone suggested I needed to call the PHP from the command line with the variables first to get the HTML source code for that set of variables, and convert it using `wkhtmltopdf`.

How do I do this? What is the process using the above URL as an example?

Comment: You can do this directly. You just need to escape the url in the command line. Put it in quotes or something. Anyway, this isn't a SO question, this belongs on serverfault.

Comment: Who gives a crap where it's posted? I never would have found this on serverfault and I needed to know this information. Get over yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux you can use the [wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) command to get a result HTML file from an URL:

```
wget "http://localhost/mypage.php?clientid=SJC&amp;datestart=201201&amp;dateend=201202"
```

Or

```
wget -O myfile.html "http://localhost/mypage.php?clientid=SJC&amp;datestart=201201&amp;dateend=201202"
```

to output the result to specific file, for example, *myfile.html*

Note:

```
wget wget -O myfile.html "http://localhost/mypage.php?clientid=SJC&datestart=201201&dateend=201202"
```

Double quote seems to solve the ampersand encoding problem.

Comment: 'host' parameter is missed. It should look something like this: `wget http://localhost/mypage.php?clientid=SJC&datestart=201201&dateend=201202`

Comment: Using the wget -O method only seems to identify the first query. I get 2 undefined index. Date start and date end. When i type exactly the same address in my browser it loads perfectly. Any Suggestions?

Comment: The ampersand "&" must be encoded as "&amp;" in url. Also is a good idea to double quote the url `wget -O myfile.html "http://localhost/mypage.php?clientid=SJC&amp;datestart=201201&amp;dateend=201202"`

Comment: Why double "wget"? - `wget wget -O myfile.html ...`

Comment: Encoding "&" as "&amp;" may not work (the parameter will be ignored). Instead, encoding "&" as "%3F" ([percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)) may work. Can you verify?

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way would be using `$_SERVER['argv']` instead of the GET variables.

However, if you HAVE to use the GET variables, you can set them in a custom script:

```
$_REQUEST['var1'] = $_SERVER['argv'][0];
```

and then `require()` the PHP script itself.

Another way would be to set the environment variables `QUERY_STRING` and `REQUEST_METHOD`:

```
export REQUEST_METHOD=GET
exprt QUERY_STRING='var1=blub&var2=blah'
```

Comment: Okay thank you for your response :)

So at the moment I have 

code $sClientid=$_GET['clientid']

can i replace that with this?

$sClientid=$_SERVER['argv'][1] ?

If so what do i need to put into the command line to generate an html page populated using the 3 variables above?

If i can get the html page its easy to convert to pdf

Many thanks